# Hierarchical product structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a report that is in pic basic(yippee) and converting it to .NET.  The report looks below in the end. The table(only showing a portion of data to keep it simple) has the ParentID(ID) and the ChildID in it and basically joins until there isn't a ChildID available(NULL). I wrote a procedure which I thought would run fine, but sits and doesn't return any type of results. SQL is not my strong point.

**Report**

```
0.........  SA33028
 1........  42S0131
 1........  5S0127
 1........  6S0175
 1........  SA33023
  2.......  16S0142
  2.......  18S0103
  2.......  24S0108
  2.......  28SM0105
  2.......  S30461.AI
  2.......  S30463
   3......  S28807
   3......  S28807
  2.......  S30641
  2.......  S31134
  2.......  S9383
  2.......  SA29801
   3......  16S0116
   3......  S27798
   3......  S31170
   3......  SA30059
    4.....  38S0116
    4.....  7S0105
    4.....  S19430.145
     5....  7SM0145
      6...  7SM0145.001
      6...  7SM0145.002
     5....  S19430
    4.....  S19431
  2.......  SA30910
```

**Table:**

```
ParentID      ChildID
SA33028   42S0131
SA33028   5S0127
SA33028   6S0175
SA33028   79S0101
SA33028   S11870
SA33028   S30151
SA33028   SA33023
SA33028   SA33029
SA33023   S30463
S30463    S28807
```

**SQL Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getHierarchy]
@Parent VARCHAR(20)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH AllParts([PSNbr], [ChildID], [ParentID])
AS 
(
 SELECT Child.Parent_Part AS PSNbr, 
 Child.Parent_Part AS ChildID, 
 Parent.Parent_Part AS ParentID
 FROM ps AS Child
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ps AS Parent
 ON Child.Component_Part = Parent.Parent_Part

 UNION ALL

 SELECT AllParts.PSNbr AS PSNbr,
    AllParts.ParentID AS ChildID, 
    NewParent.Component_Part AS ParentID
 FROM AllParts
 INNER JOIN PS AS NewParent
 ON AllParts.ParentID = NewParent.Parent_Part
    AND AllParts.ParentID <> AllParts.ChildID
 INNER JOIN PS as NewParentInfo
 ON NewParent.Component_Part = NewParentInfo.Parent_Part

)
SELECT AllParts.[PSNbr],
       AllParts.[ParentID]
FROM AllParts
WHERE PSNbr = @Parent;
```

Comment: What do the results from your SQL statement need to look like in order for you to generate the report?

Comment: Like the intial report in the example. Where is has 0-x # level.

Answer (score 0):

In honor of the KISS principle, I shall ask. How are you testing the procedure? Do you just hit F5 or run it from within SQL? Try highlighting from "BEGIN" through to your "END" and then hitting F5. (as an aside, you have no "END" in the sample above)

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that and it slowly grows and runs forever. I finally killed it after 45 minutes. The table has about 580,000 records in it, which isn't huge my any means, but not terrible small either. And the data it is returning right now isn't correct, because it is giving back multiples in the parentid department.

Comment: Your table sample does have duplicate values for ParentID. Also, Left Joins, and Unions are both prone to causing duplicates.  Try removing these pieces one at a time and see when the duplicate results are removed.

Comment: I'll give it a go. The starting level(@Parent = 'SA33028') will have multiple parentID's because they have different children. I will be searching on a particular starting parentID then branching out from there. I might end up having to do a looping sequence to get everything somehow.

Comment: I don't think it can be done this way which so many levels. This hierarchy can be 9 levels deep(5 in the example above from the report)

Comment: In the sample report you show, what does the first column represent?

Comment: That is the level or hierarchy. I probably should edit and explain it a bit better. You initially start out with a part number(parent part) and from there have in this example have 8 parts(component_parts or children) underneath it. Then those could have parts and so on and so forth. The original PSNbr looks like Parent_Part*Component. I split these up to match them easier.